# How to preview multiple Thumbnail images before upload in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript

### In this only one image show. I want to preview multiple images.

I try this code

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImagePreview(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#<%=img.ClientID%>').prop('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(240)
                    .height(150);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nitika That's work

```
<input type="file" name="imageUploader" value="" id="imageUploader" multiple="">
<div id="imgViewer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                $('#imgViewer').empty();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#imgViewer').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    $('#imgViewer').append($('<img>', { src: e.target.result, width: '50px', height: '50' }));
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    $("#imageUploader").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for viewing my question but it does not show images

Comment: Did you insert  <div id="imgViewer" ></div> above your script ?

Comment: I had done ... Thanks, Mahmoud Hassan ... Actually, I used your code and my code ...... and finally my problem is solved.

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="True" onchange="ShowImagePreview(this);"  /> <div id="imgViewer"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">function ShowImagePreview(input) {if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {for (var i = 0 ; i < input.files.length; i++) {var reader = new FileReader();reader.onload = function (e) { $('#imgViewer').append($('<img>', { src: e.target.result, width: '50px', height: '50' })); }; reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);}}}
    </script>